# Encriptar datos por via URL en Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, url

Estoy enviando datos por url de un formulario a una página cualquiera, pero el problema es que en esa página su url que recibe los datos NO estan encriptados.

**Este es mi código:**

```
Response.Redirect("SimuladorExamen.aspx?dni=" & Server.UrlEncode(txtDNI.Text) & "&apellidoPaterno=" & Server.UrlEncode(txtApellidoPaterno.Text) & "&apellidoMaterno=" & Server.UrlEncode(txtApellidoMaterno.Text) + "&nombreCompleto=" & Server.UrlEncode(txtNombres.Text), False)
```

Como ven, le estoy poniendo el Server.UrlEncode y nada.

**Y con esto las recibo en la otra página:**

```
Dim dni As String = Request.QueryString(Server.UrlDecode("dni")).ToString
Dim nombreCompleto As String = Request.QueryString(Server.UrlDecode("nombreCompleto")).ToString
Dim apellidoPaterno As String = Request.QueryString(Server.UrlDecode("apellidoPaterno")).ToString
Dim apellidoMaterno As String = Request.QueryString(Server.UrlDecode("apellidoMaterno")).ToString
```

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: E incorporar un método anterior a enviar los datos que los cifre con alguna librería y luego que en el otro lado los descifres?

Comment: Hola @Cristian Damian Vena, efectivamente, eso es lo que estoy haciendo. Ya encontre una y dentro de un poco la publico.